# Mac Calendar and Google Application Password

Tags: google-apps, google-calendar

Following a system update, all Apple apps looking to Google required new Google Application Passwords. Generating and entering this enabled Mail, Notes and Messages to sync again.

Not so much with Calendar. I can find no field in Calendar into which to enter the GAP. Does anyone know what Calendar requires when it's lost it's link to Google, as different from Mail, Notes and Messages? I'm running OS X Yosemite on a Mac Mini.

Comment: Since you're asking about a setting in the Mac app, your question would probably be better off at [apple.se].

Comment: That said, I *think* you need the iCal link from your calendar settings.